# chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab returning undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I was able to capture sites like StackOverflow w3schools.com etc. But it actually not working when dealing with Google pages (Youtube, Drive etc.) It seems there's a limit when using captureVisibleTab in development stage. Should I need to publish the app first so it can run?

Here's the code snippet.

background.js

```
var triggerCapture = function() {
    chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(null, {format:'png'},function(imageURI){
        console.log("captureVisibleTab");   alert(imageURI) // undefined
    }); };
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Queue taker",
  "version": "0.1",
  "description": "Demonstrate screenshot functionality in the chrome.tabs api.",

"background": {
    "persistent": false,
    "page": "screenshot.html"
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "camera.png",
    "default_title": "Queue taker"
  },

  "permissions": "<all_urls>","tabs","activeTab"
  ],

  "content_security_policy":"script-src 'self' https://www.gstatic.com/ https://*.firebaseio.com https://www.googleapis.com; object-src 'self'",

  "manifest_version": 2
```

Error

> : Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabs.captureVisibleTab:
>   This page cannot be scripted due to an ExtensionsSettings policy.
>       at triggerCapture (chrome-extension://jciafjhdkmanfegbanccjagihhegecpo/background.js:17:17)
>       at chrome-extension://jciafjhdkmanfegbanccjagihhegecpo/background.js:24:5

Comment: The error message seems pretty straightforward: your enterprise policy prevents the access.

Comment: Is there any workaround?

Comment: Well that would be a big security hole, I guess. You can try using a different browser, like Firefox.